# How to compute the rank of a smooth map between submanifolds of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

I have to solve different exercises where I am asked to show that a (smooth) map $f:M\to N$, where $M$ and $N$ are smooth manifolds, is an immersion/a submersion. This basically boils down to computing $d_x f$ and looking at the rank of this matrix.

I can do this just fine by taking coordinate charts and all that jazz, but that is a really long way to do this. I say it is a really long way because my instructor showed us another way to do this when $M$ and $N$ are acutally embedded into some $\mathbb{R}^m$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$, respectively, but I don't really rigorously understand why this works.

Let me give you an example to make myself clear. Consider the map $f:S^2\to \mathbb{R}^3$, $f(x, y, z)=(x, y, z-2z^3)$. We want to show that this is an immersion. So, what he did was to look at $f$ as a map $\mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}^3$. Now it is easy to compute the differential of $f$ in the usual way (i.e. just like in multivariable calculus) and we see that this matrix has rank $3$ if $z\ne \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}$, so we may conclude that $d_{(x, y, z)} f|_{S^2}$ is injective, i.e. $f$ is an immersion, if $z\ne \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt 6}$ (and we can conclude this for any point in $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $z\ne \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}$, not just on our restriction to $S^2$). So, we only need to look at those points on $S^2$ where $z=\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt 6}$ and in order for $f$ to be an immersion we must have $\operatorname{Ker} d_{(x, y, \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt 6})} f\cap T_{(x, y, \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt 6})}S^2=\{0\}$, which is intuitively clear to me (just like what we did before), we are restricting the kernel of $df$ to the actual tangent space where we want it to be injective. But why do these tricks actually work? I mean, if I compute the differential as a map $S^2 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ using charts it is obviously going to be a different matrix than the one I got. Why can I just intersect that kernel and the tangent space? And why can I just look at the differential as a map $\mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}^3$ in the first case too?

Furthermore, what if we had a map $\mathbb{R}^3\to S^2$? Or a map $S^2\to S^2$? Are there similar tricks in those cases that allow me to avoid actually computing the differential using charts and just looking at my map as a $\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ map and make further amends to obtain the actual rank of my map?

Comment: You can write $f = g \circ i$ where $i: S^2\to R^3$ is the inclusion map and $g: R^3\to R^3$ is defined by the same formula as $f$. Now $d f = d g \circ d i$ and the composition of two injections is an injection.

Comment: @Gribouillis I see, so this finishes off the case when $z\ne \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt 6}$, right?

Comment: Exactly, and it gives also the other condition $\text{Ker}(d g)\cap \text{Im}(d i) = \{0\}$ when $z = \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}$.

Comment: @Gribouillis damn, you're right, this is straight linear algebra. This is really nice, thanks a lot. What about the other cases I mentioned of maps $\mathbb{R}^3\to S^2$ or $S^2 \to S^3$? I don't see any nice trick here because I can no longer use the inclusion map.

Comment: If $f: R^3\to S^2$ you can consider $g = i \circ f\ :\ R^3\to R^3$. For the case $f: S^2\to S^3$, if you know a $g$ such that $ f = g\circ i$, you could consider $j\circ g\ :\ R^3\to R^4$ and draw conclusions from their jacobian matrices.

Comment: @Gribouillis thanks a lot, I think I figured this out now.

Comment: @Gribouillis another question came to my mind now: can these tricks also help us find the differential of our map $f$, not only its rank?